# Convert two ArrayLists to String[][]

Tags: java, arrays

What would be the best way to convert two lists into 2D Array? Example

```
listA = {"A","B"}
listB = {"1","2"}
```

I want to convert them to:
    array = {{A ,1},
             {B ,2}}

Is there a better way than doing it with manually with loops?

Comment: Please define "better" ...

Comment: It is called `zip()` and you can do it using a few third-party libraries such as Guava and Functional Java, each time with some quirks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip

Comment: If by chance you are using doubles (not String) then apache math commons has a way to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292950/how-to-get-the-transpose-of-a-matrix-array-in-java

Comment: @alamar: I'm not sure that 'zip()' the right name is. The examples I found are 2 arrays into one combining them like that: {"A","1","B","2"}. This is not a 2D Array with 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your want. Just doing simplest way as below.
Here, I assume `listA` and `listB` are same size.

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add("A");
listA.add("B");
listA.add("C");
List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
listB.add("1");
listB.add("2");
listB.add("3");
String[][] multi = new String[listA.size()][listB.size()];
for(int i=0; i < listA.size(); i++) {
    multi[i] = new String[]{listA.get(i), listB.get(i)};
}
System.out.println(multi[0][0] + "," + multi[0][1]);
System.out.println(multi[1][0] + "," + multi[1][1]);
System.out.println(multi[2][0] + "," + multi[2][1]);
```

Output

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
```