# Matrix transpose in java(need explanation)

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

This is my code, it should work, but when i transpose and print matrix, it outputs the same matrix, not transposed.
Some explanation?
It should change the matrix, not make copy and transpose then return.
public void transpose(){

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            Object tmp=matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i]=tmp;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hint: try printing your matrix after every loop step. Start with small matrices; and use different values for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got wrong indices in the inner loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            Object tmp = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = tmp ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't transpose your matrix since you are overwriting your originally matrix by `matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i];`

Here is a way to tranpose a matrix in Java: [transpose double[][] matrix with a java function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497288/5867869)